# how to edit the existing content in the angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Im creating an app using ionic and angularjs. The problem I face is in the editing. I have a two view pages, one view will list the car names, when a car name is selected it will be redirect to the second view page where the information regarding the selected car is listed and also editable . Im able to get it till here but I don't know how to edit the content. I tried using `contenteditable` along with `<div>` property but angularjs can't bind the ng-model property. So please help me how to edit the read information so that the edited information are updated. Thank you.

```
  Selected Car:
     <input type="text" ng-model="editedName">{{selectInput.name}}</div>
     <br><hr>
    Selected options: 
    <div ng-repeat="type in selectInput.types" ng-model="selectedTypes"> 
     {{type}}
    </div>  
    </div>
    <br><hr>
     <button ng-click="Update($index)">Update</button></div>
```

Comment: Can your prepare [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?.